# Контролирование атрибутов при помощи XSD Схемы 1.0

Tags: xml, xsd

Подскажите, в XSD Схеме 1.0 можно ли:

1. Контролировать наличие одного или другого атрибута в элементе, причем должен быть либо один, либо другой (одновременное присутствие исключено)

   - `<el value_1="11" value_2="22" />` - Ошибка, присутствуют оба элемента.
   - `<el value_1="11" />` - Проверку проходит
   - `<el value_2="22" />` - Проверку проходит
2. Контролировать наличие атрибута или, если его нет, наличие дочернего элемента

   - `<el value="11"/>` - проверку проходит
   - `<el><value>11</value></el>` - проверку проходит
   - `<el value="11"><value>11</value>` - Ошибка, присутствует и атрибут и вложенный элемент
3. Контролировать наличие атрибута или содержимое элемента.

   - `<el value="11" />` - проверку проходит
   - `<el>11</el>` - проверку проходит
   - `<el value="11">11</el>` - ошибка, присутствует и атрибут и вложенные данные

Вычитал, что в XSD Schema 1.1 такие можно контролировать, создавая свои правила контроля при помощи xs:assert, но увы, используется схема версии 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нет. Такое возможно только для элементов
2. Нет. Все, что можно - это объявить элемент и/или атрибут обязательными или нет
3. Нет.

Если у Вас такие хитрые правила, то можно валидировать при помощи XSL

> `<el value_1="11" value_2="22" />` - Ошибка, присутствуют оба элемента.

```
<xsl:template match="el">
  <xsl:if test="@value_1 and @value_2>
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">
      Опаньки!
    </xsl:message>
</xsl:template>
```

Ну или вначале преобразовать входной документ во что-то валидируемое, а потом натравить XSD. И обрабатывать уже преобразованный документ

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что они взаимоисключающие? Т.е. либо валидацию производить через xsd или через xsl. Никогда последнее не использовал. Через XMLDocument (C#) данную схему валидации можно использовать? VS 2013 поддерживает такой стандарт?

Comment: @pincher1519 Нет. Не взаимоисключающее. Даже наоборот я бы рекомендовал вначале использовать XSD, чтобы отсеять крупные проблемы, а потом через XSL провести тюнинг. Через XMLDocument можно. Просто вызываете трансформацию. VS2013 - это компилятор. Ему пофигу, что Вы используете в программе

Comment: @Anton_Shchyrov, Заметил, что сама по себе схема xsd на основе себя же может контролировать наличие атрибутов и элементов. Но не понимаю, как она это делает. Например xs:element может иметь атрибут type, если внутри элемента нет xs:complextype или xs:simpletype. Если данные элементы будут указаны element, то атрибут тип нельзя указывать. Как они на уровне Схемы данную проверку реализовали?

Comment: @pincher1519 Проверил. Элемент легко живет с атрибутом type и вложенным complexType. По крайней мере при валидации такой схемы схемой XMLSchema.xsd ошибок не возникло

Comment: @Anton_Shchyrov действительно. А студия выкидывает ошибку. Значит как-то дополнительно проверяет схему.